# Importing or requiring a javascript file twice for mocha testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm writing a spec to test the variance in a javascript file based on the existence of global.window.  Is there some way to import or require a particular file twice?  Once before and once after setting global.window.

The file being tested looks something like this:

```
let someObject = (windowExists => {
  return windowExists ? 'abc' : '123';
})(typeof window !== 'undefined');

export default someObject;
```

I was hoping to use this pattern, but it doesn't seem viable seeing as both common.js and es6 modules both only include the file one time and deal with a cached version thereafter.

Comment: You can export a function you can call that checks for window each time instead

Comment: I considered this as an alternative.  Just returning it from the get-go felt more eloquent to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is easier than most people realize. All modules required are stored on `require.cache`. You can simply delete the module from the cache and then requiring it will no longer pull the module from the cache. The key of the cached module is the full path of the module, which you can get using `require.resolve` if you don't want to type the full path.

```
require('./myModule.js');
delete require.cache[require.resolve('./myModule.js')];
require('./myModule.js');
```

Without clearing the cache:
[image]

With clearing the cache:
[image]

Comment: The only drawback to this is that built-ins are not cached in `require.cache`, so they cannot be forced to re-load themselves in this fashion. But, that's probably not a very frequent use case, even when doing unit testing.

Comment: Thanks for the information!  This is handy.

Comment: Plus one for the screenshots in vim ;)

Comment: IMO this is not a good solution in that module should be self-contained. The answer is correct and all, but I would suggest taking another approach entirely.

Comment: The module is self-contained. I don't understand what you mean. Clearing the module cache is happening within the context of a test suite. I'm fine with doing more low level work to clean up between tests personally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`vm.runInContext()`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_script_runincontext_contextifiedsandbox_options) function to execute arbitrary JavaScript (as string) against a given, possibly isolated, context. Within that context, you can set the value of `window` to be either `undefined` or any other value suitable for your needs.

There are actually more ways to achieve the same result using the `vm` module, but the general principle remains:

1. Load the JavaScript code under test as a string
2. Create a pre-determined global state you would like the script to be executed in
3. Execute the script
4. Observe the result